# Domain Registration

Tags: domains

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Who is a great domain registrar company?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9/who-is-a-great-domain-registrar-company)

Hi, I'm about to make my first domain purchase, actually I'm going to buy in bulk ...

Any idea about a good host and registrar? I`m looking for a good host with lots of features and not expensive.

Comment: This question is very broad

Comment: This is a difficult question to answer well. Whenever I've seen it asked you get a number of people answering with either the host that they are happy with, or a host that they had problems with. Their experiences are generally limited to a small number of hosts. There are a number of sites which let people rate hosts according to reliability, quality of support and so on, so then the question is "which is the best host-rating site?". I'm not aware of any (host-rating)-rating sites so you can answer that question. A search for "host rating" will find a number of host rating sites.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that 1and1 continue to have the cheapest domain names. And they have automatic renewal which is very good for someone buying domains in bulk. They have a very easy to use system.

As for hosting, you really can't beat Webfaction. They are affordable and flexible and super super easy to use (especially if you are hosting multiple sites).

I've used a bunch of different hosts and registars and those two are hard to beat.

Godaddy and Hostgator are super popular, but I beleive that is because they offer amazing affiliate deals - not because they have a good product. I've used both on clients sites and they are frustratingly slow and difficult to use compared to my 1and1 and webfaction setup.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [UK Web Solutions Direct](http://ukwebsolutionsdirect.co.uk) for years and have never had any problems.  They are reliable and not too expensive.

On the flip side, I have used [easyspace](http://blog.ajcw.com/2011/01/easyspace-easy-theft/) once and they were expensive, difficult to use and with extremely poor customer service.