# Buying/registering domain name

Tags: url, domains

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Who is a great domain registrar company?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9/who-is-a-great-domain-registrar-company)

What is the best place to buy/register a domain name? (eg. to get a web site like www.mysite.com) Also, once I have that how can I add content there? Any suggestions ? I am a bit new to this web business/programming so I apologize if this sounds like a funny question. Thanks.

Comment: This is not a programming related question. Try the "webmaster" stack-exchange site.

Answer (score 0):

There are many places and I suggest you take a look at this list

http://lists.econsultant.com/top-10-domain-name-registrars.html

It seems though that you would like to have hosting for this as well so if you want files to be hosted too then check out this one instead

http://webhostinggeeks.com/

To add content the hosts usually have ways of uploading like [FTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol)

Answer (score 0):

Your asking about two different services. Domain registration and Web hosting. If your a beginner it will be simpler to buy both services from the same company. It's the hosting part you need to look into as this even for very cheap hosting it will cost you 5x more and there are more options to consider with hosting.

Assuming your site is going to be simple go to one of the big name hosting companies and buy their cheapest package. The large companies are used to dealing with beginners and will have help articles on their site to guide you through. In the UK big consumer hosts are 123-reg,1&1 and heart internet. I don't know about other countries, unless you have reason not to go with a provider in the same country as you are located.

If you planing a complex site that would cause you financial loss of it went down then employ a professional.