# Why do sites redirect to the canonical URL if it can parse a page correctly given any slug?

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, canonical-url

Several sites that I have come across, including Stackoverflow, perform a 301 redirect when given an "incorrect" slug. For example:

```
http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9/incorrect-slug
```

will be redirected permanently to:

```
http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9/who-is-a-great-domain-registrar-company
```

But <strike>since</strike> assuming that the canonical URL is already specified, wouldn't the search engine point to the correct URL? What is the rationale for doing a redirect if the a page does not require the slug to parse correctly?

Further, is it a prerequisite to have at least a link pointing to the canonical URL in order for the page to be ranked? Will Google add search result to the canonical URL `http://mysite.com/user/1/joe` if all my links point to `http://mysite.com/user/1`?

Comment: 'But since the canonical URL is already specified' - How do you know the canonical is specified if the page redirects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you know, in Stack Exchange, edits can be made to the title. By this reason, for a single question, there can be generated as many URLs as titles had the question. Those older edited titles generate obsolete URLs that shouldn't exist and should 301 redirect to the fresh updated one.

`301 redirect` is [better than rel="canonical"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PuY49ZB-yqg), because you're avoiding Google from <strike>indexing</strike> crawling infinite pages (as you have infinite possible slugs) with the same content, all of them pointing to the same canonical.

`rel="canonical"` is better used for URLs that should exist, like URLs with parameters that generate the same content between them (i.e. in-site searches, URLs with tracking parameters), but that should not be redirected.

About your last two questions, in your case `rel="canonical"` will work fine because all generated links point to pages with the **exact same content** and Google finds it easy to associate them and not index the duplicated ones.

But you can't tell a search engine to "point" to the URL that you consider the best, Google may index both the canonical and the non-canonical if it considers that good for SERPs.

Comment: `you're avoiding Google from indexing infinite pages with the same content` do you mean that Google will still index the non-canonical page even if the canonical one is specified?

Comment: The second part of my question is not answered.

Comment: Google crawls pages with canonical, and actually indexes it, but it decides whether to show them or not using several signals https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394, a very important one is that the page should have most of its content duplicated

Comment: updated answer...

Comment: Thanks for the update, I have posted a similar question on [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198230) and it reaffirms your final point.

Answer (score 2):

> **Several sites that I have come across, including Stackoverflow, perform a 301 redirect when given an "incorrect" slug.**

The web server for those sites is configured to redirect to a "catch-all" URL should a portion of the URL be missing. In the example you provided:

```
http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9/incorrect-slug
```

If anything after the `9/` is added, it will redirect to:

```
http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9/who-is-a-great-domain-registrar-company
```

> **But assuming that the canonical URL is already specified, wouldn't the search engine point to the correct URL?**

[Canonical URLs](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en&ref_topic=2371375) are for indicating the preferred URL to index. In the case of redirecting an incomplete, non-existing URL to an existing one, canonical URLs are not really a factor - only the target page of the redirect will be seen.

> **What is the rationale for doing a redirect if the a page does not require the slug to parse correctly?**

One reason for redirecting a non-existent URL to an existing URL is to keep the visitor on the site by showing a popular page (or question in this case) instead of an error page, which may lead to lower [bounce rates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounce_rate).

> **Further, is it a prerequisite to have at least a link pointing to the canonical URL in order for the page to be ranked?**

A [canonical link](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en) is a link, so providing Google finds the canonical link somewhere, it *may* index it, depending on the criteria of its algorithm.

Comment: I don't think you should label a URL non-existent when it still works correctly. Of course I wouldn't be able to tell whether this is so on Stackoverflow since it forces a redirect. I am just questioning the rationale for doing so _if_ search engines are programmed to read canonical URLs and index it properly.

Comment: In your example, `http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/9/incorrect-slug` does not exist, regardless of the redirect. Again, canonical URLs are not a factor because it will never been seen by the search engine in a URL that's being redirected. See moobot's comment above.

Comment: I would agree with you if this is a static html webpage. But for Stackoverflow, I believe, the page is generated dynamically. What I am trying to say is that instead of forcing a redirect, Stackoverflow can design its site such that it accepts whatever slug it is given and generate the page with a canonical link pointing to the correct URL. It doesn't have to do a redirect _unless_ there is a _good reason_ to do so.

Comment: What's the benefit of generating a page with a canonical link for pages that don't exist, and wouldn't be indexed by a search engine in the first place? I provided a good reason why they might redirect to a page that does exists like they do.

Comment: An additional call to the database has to be made on each redirect because the redirect is handled by the page itself after polling the database and checking that an incorrect title is given. This is not something trivial that can be handled by the server config alone. The point is not about generating these pages with an incorrect slug, but the treatment by the search engine if someone were to edit the page title and hence changing the slug and whether such pages really require a 301 redirect or if the canonical link is sufficient, thereby conserving server resources.

Comment: `or if the canonical link is sufficient` sufficient for what?

Comment: Sufficient to produce same SEO result as compared to a 301 redirect.

Comment: A canonical URL is to used to tell search engines the preferred page to index when another page has the same content. The only bearing on SEO that it has is to prevent issues with duplicate content. 301 redirects might help to maintain search engine results if redirected to the same content. However, in the example you provided, we're not sure if that's a 301 or other type of redirect.